# Angular2 Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {StockComponent} from './stock.component';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import './rxjs-operators';
    @Injectable() 
export class StockApiService {
    symbol: string
    public stocks = [

    ];

    purchased = ["",""];
    constructor(private http: Http) {
        http.get('http://localhost:8000/stock/' + this.symbol)
            .map(res => res.json())
            //parameter   //key          
            // .subscribe(stockInfo =>  this.stocks.push(stockInfo))
            .subscribe(stockInfo => console.log(stockInfo))
    }

    getStockInfo(symbol : string) {
        this.purchased.push(symbol);
        let stockLink: string = 'http://localhost:8000/stock/' + symbol;
        //writing logic for get stock search bar
    }
    //retrieves stock from array
    getStock (symbol : string) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.stocks.length; i++) {
            if (symbol.toLowerCase() === this.stocks[i].symbol.toLowerCase()) {
                return this.stocks[i];
            }

        }
    }
}
```

obviously there are a lot more files but this is the service i'm working in. also new to angular2 so let me explain what i know is going on and what i'm doing.

I'm creating a stock market simulator and i'm trying to get the data from google to my front end of angular2. So i did some really hacky stuff and I have a second node server with cors getting data from google, and I have my angular2 sending a get request to my server so I can display it on the front end. I realized that google is not returning to me JSON and rather it is returning to me HTML? or just javascript because it looks like an array.

So my i'm taking this link http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=' and I have an input field which is going to take the value (symbol) inputted attach it onto this url, then I want to get the data I need through what google returns to me. 
So if anyone can help me, im new to angular2 and this is a lot to handle

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(res)`? (before `.json()`)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I get back code: {_body: "httpserver.cc: Response Code 400↵", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "Ok", headers: Headers…}
_body
:
"httpserver.cc: Response Code 400↵"
headers
:
Headers
ok
:
true
status
:
200
statusText
:
"Ok"
type
:
2
url
:
"http://localhost:8000/stock/undefined"
__proto__
:
Object
arrayBuffer
:
()
blob
:
()
constructor
:
Response(responseOptions)
json
:
()
text
:
()
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: Seems your server forwards some "Bad request" (400) it gets from its call to the Google service to your Angular client.

Comment: could that be because  http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q= doesn't have a symbol to query for? for example if i attach  http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=amd i get back AMD's stock information but because i haven't set up the onclick function to link this request with the input field its just auto running on page load

Comment: Sorry, no idea. I can only help with Angular, no knowlege about finance.google.com